# Blazo WASM - Separate into multiple components (MudBlazor)

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, webassembly, mudblazor

I have an edit form, with multiple MudTabPanels inside.
Problem is, I have LOTS of properties for this class, and we've decided to split into multiple panels, that each contain an edit form with different forms/inputs.

Format is somewhat like this (pseudo-razor-code) :

```
<MudTabs>
    <MudTabPanel Text="Section 1">
        <EditForm>
                <MudItem>
                         <EditField Property1>
                         <EditField Property2>
                          ...
                         <EditField Property 10>
      </EditForm>
   </MudTabPanel>
<MudTabPanel Text="Section 2">
        <EditForm>
                <MudItem>
                         <EditField Propertyn11>
                         <EditField Propertyn12>
                          ...
                         <EditField Property 20>
      </EditForm>
   </MudTabPanel>
 ..... lots of other panels here
<MudTabPanel Text="Section N">
        <EditForm>
                <MudItem>
                         <EditField Property98>
                         <EditField Property99>
                          ...
                          <EditField Property100>
      </EditForm>
   </MudTabPanel>
</MudTabs>
```

Problem is :
I have +1000 lines of code just in this razor page!
VS 2022 Preview is struggling to give me a decent performance (on the UI seems to be working fine)but modifying just a property is a pain in the ass in VS.

I was thinking about moving each Panel into a separate component , and transmitting my entity as a Parameter.

But:
1).Right now, because I use all these into a single page razor, on the code page, let's say I have the method DoSomething(), I can use this method on each panel.
Will I need to repeat the DoSomething() on each component, if i'll split them ? Is there a way I can share that method?
2).Do you think this will impact the performance on the UI?
3).Is there any better way of doing this ?

LE: Updated my data binding example

Code behind:

```
private Article _article;
```

Example of some bindings in my first tab:

```
<MudNumericField T="int?" @bind-value="_article.ArticleID">
 <MudSelect @bind-Value="_article.UnitPriceIntervals" OffsetY="true" Label="Unit Price Interval" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Margin="Margin.Dense" Dense="true">
    @foreach (UnitPriceIntervals? item in (UnitPriceIntervals[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(UnitPriceIntervals)))
          {
           <MudSelectItem Value="item">@item</MudSelectItem>
          }
        </MudSelect>
```

Now, my article properties can also contain references to other data types that are stored in a different SQL table, with possibility to change them, based on a search.
Example :

```
 _article.GeneralText1 = 1234
```

Comment: How did you eventually solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a

```
@foreach (FieldAttributes fsa in cAtribs)
    {
    <MudTabPanel Text=@fsa.key>
        <EditForm>
                <MudItem>
                     @for(int i=0;i<fsa.Value.Count();i++)
                         {
                         <EditField @fsa.Value.ElementAt(i) />
                          }
                </MudItem>
      </EditForm>
   </MudTabPanel>
    }
```

loop, where `Dictionary<string, List<string>> cAtribs`.

The key of the dictionary is "Section 1", ... "Section N" and the collection has the property names for each section.

you can build `cAtribs` ahead of time, or dynamically, or even using reflection.

Comment: Problem is, EditField could be a NumericField type for one property, and a Select for other property, or something else for other property.

Comment: I suspected as much. So this is where reflection will come in.

Comment: Obviously reflection is needed only for a generic form. If you know in advance which field is numric etc, it would be easy enough to build this info into cAtrins or an additional structure.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a comment than an answer, but there's not enough spacing to fit it into a comment.

1. Track which Tab you're in and only load the edit form for the specific tab.  That will significantly reduce what needs to be rendered at one time.  Something like:

```
@if (tabNo = 2) 
{
// Edit Form 2
}
```

2. You don't show your data binding, but make sure you use a view data service to hold your model data.
3. Consider using a component for each edit form within a Tab?

There are many complications with multi-tab editors/wizards.  How are you validating and when?  Is you backend one model/data table?

If you want more detail, add a comment and I'll try and put together some demo code later today.

===== Update

First get your data out of your edit component and into a ViewService. Here's a wire framework for one.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StackOverflow.Answers
{
    public class ArticleViewService
    {
        //set up your data access
        // load as Scoped Service - one per user session

        public Article Article { get; private set; }

        public Task GetArticle()
        {
            // Your get article code here
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task SaveArticle()
        {
            // Your save article code here
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Next your section edit components.  Your data comes from the inject view service and gets updated directly into the same service.  No passing data between componnts.

```
<h3>Section1</h3>
<EditForm EditContext="_editContext">
    <InputText @bind-Value="ViewService.Article.Name"></InputText>
// or your mud editor components
    .....
</EditForm>
@code {

    [Inject] private ArticleViewService ViewService { get; set; }

    private EditContext _editContext;

        protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
        _editContext = new EditContext(ViewService.Article);
            return base.OnInitializedAsync();
        }

}
```

Then you Article editor, with MudTabs.  This should track the active tab and display only the correct section component.  I haven't tested this but it "should" work (I don't use MudBlazor and don't have it installed.)

```
<MudTabs @bind-ActivePanelIndex="this.panelId">
    <MudTabPanel Text="Item One" ID='"pn_one"'>
        @if(this.PanelId = 1)
            {
                \\ Section 1 componwnt
            }
    </MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="Item Two" ID='"pn_two"'>
        @if (this.PanelId = 2)
        {
            \\ Section 2 componwnt
        }

    </MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="Item Three" ID='"pn_three"'>
        @if (this.PanelId = 2)
        {
        \\ Section 3 componwnt
       }
    </MudTabPanel>
</MudTabs>

@code {

    private int PanelId {
        get => _panelId;
        set => {
            if (value != _panelId )
            {
                _panelId = value;
                StateHasChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private int _panelId = 1;

}
```

Comment: i've edited my original questions, should answer your questions regarding point 2

Comment: Meanwhile, i've already started moving them into components, by sending the _article as a parameter to each separate tab.